# What is the derivative of $f(x)=(\sin^{3}(5x))^{\frac{1}{4}}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the derivative of the following function?

$$f(x)=(\sin^{3}(5x))^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

So I did the chain rule and I got

$$(\frac{1}{4})((\sin^{3}(5x))^{-3/4})(3\sin^2(5x))(\cos(5x))(5).$$

Does that look right? How do I simplify that? Thank you for the help and feedback!

Comment: Yes..it is correct!

Comment: awesome! how do I simplify that? That's where I seem to get stuck on these sorts of problems.

Comment: $\sin^3(x)=(\sin x)^3$...

Comment: collect the exponents. will be some multiple of $\frac{\cos(5x)}{\sin^?(5x)}$

Comment: May be you first simplify your given function as $(\sin 5x)^\frac{3}{4}$..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you can do better by starting with $$(\sin 5x)^\frac{3}{4}$$

Then, its derivative w.r.t. $x$ is $$\frac{3}{4}(\sin 5x)^{-\frac{1}{4}}.\cos 5x. 5=\frac{15}{4}(\sin 5x)^{-\frac{1}{4}}.\cos 5x$$ Nothing simplifies more!

Comment: $\large{\frac{15}{2}(\sin 5x)^{-\frac{5}{4}}.\sin 10x}$ if you apply double angle rule...tops

Comment: Well,..then I must miss the meaning of *simplify* :)

Comment: applied $\large{\sin 2x = 2(\sin x)(\cos x)}$